# No margins displayed in Layout view of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, borders, arcgis-10.7

I have an issue with Layout View in ArcMap.  I need the layout view to look like this (note the white margins around the map):

[image]

At the moment, it looks like this:

[image]

My version of ArcGIS Desktop is 10.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data frame is much bigger than your page size. See if you can drag the data frame around to find one of its corners and then shrink it. If this doesn't work you might also want to take a look at some of the [settings related to map extent](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/customizing-your-map-extent.htm) to check if see if you've accidentally gotten it set to "fixed extent" or "fixed scale" which might be causing issues related to zooming in and resizing.

Comment: Dear Ycartwhelen, thank you for your help. However, I cannot drag the data frame in layout mode, and my map extent is set to automatic.

Comment: That's odd. Have you tried the good old, "start a new mxd and add all your layers to that" trick? And maybe add the layers one by one, checking that layout is functional before any layers and after each layer is added?

Comment: Dear Ycartwhelen, that worked! I created new mxd and added all the layers from scratch and there was no issue anymore. Many thanks for your help!! :)